# App draining battery

Tags: android, battery

I've an app that has been out in production for a year and is working ok with regard to battery life. The latest version of the app now stores some data(2k a few times per day) in the sqlite DB. It also redraws a progressbar when the signal strength changes.

One customer is saying that 20 of their staff who have the latest version, cannot make the phone battery last more than 5 hrs. It used to last 10 or 12 hrs. The above changes are the only ones i have made in the latest version.

can redrawing the view on every signal change half the battery's life over a day?

thanks Matt.

Comment: who says its your app causing the battery problem, could they not have installed another app on their phones causing the problem?

Comment: @tyczj hi, yes that's what i was thinking but i need to know if the changes that i have made could have affected things. i don't see how redrawing a progressbar could do this.

Comment: Yikes, _every_ signal change?  Isn't that multiple times a second?  The device would never go into sleep mode...

Comment: @Izkata hi, yes it does go into sleep mode, that's not a problem. I only override onSignalChanged and update view from there. I haven't created a wakelock in that part of the program.

Comment: @turtleboy You don't need a wakelock to wake the device up, just to keep it awake.  I suggest doing more testing around that anyway.  (And IIRC, there's an implicit "wakelock" during the lifetime of the callback anyway)

Comment: Have You tried http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html#timelinepanel before and after the change in order to know exactly the proccess activity?